# How to access to various databases with Ruby?

Tags: ruby

I am building a module in Ruby to read metadata from source tables in various databases. 
I wrote a small program to test with PostgreSQL:

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby
require 'pg'
begin
  puts "start"
  puts 'Version of libpg: ' + PG.library_version.to_s
  con = PG.connect(host: 'localhost', dbname: 'rdv_app_dev', user: 'rdv_app', password: 'rdv_app')
  puts con.server_version
  pst = con.exec "SELECT * FROM users"
  pst.each do |row|
    puts "%s %s " % [ row['id'], row['email'] ]
  end
  puts 'There are %d columns ' % pst.nfields
  puts 'The column names are:'
  pst.fields.each do |f|
    puts pst.fnumber(f).to_s + ' ' + f + ' ' + pst.ftype(pst.fnumber(f)).to_s
  end 
rescue PG::Error => e
  puts e.message
ensure
  pst.clear if pst
  con.close if con
  puts "stop"
end
```

It works fine, but it uses functions that are specific to Postgres. I need to have it working for any database without re-coding it for each one of them.

I read about Ruby-DBI, but it looks to be out of date, since it did not evolve for 7 years.

Is there a generic solution for accessing a database with Ruby ?

Comment: I don't see why DBI couldn't work. However you might want to take a look at Sequel or DataMapper as more recent alternatives: https://github.com/jeremyevans/sequel | http://datamapper.org/

Comment: Rubygems.org and Ruby-toolbox.com are good places to look for gems. ActiveRecord, DataMapper or other ORM gems might be what you're looking for.

Comment: [Sequel](http://sequel.jeremyevans.net) is a great tool and supports a wide variety of DBMs. Read the landing page and the Cheat Sheet to get an idea what it can do and how easily you can port code from one DBM to another.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[ActiveRecord](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_basics.html) is by far the most popular (see [RubyGems stats](https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/orm)). [DataMapper](http://datamapper.org/) is very similar, but more lightweight and makes changing the database quicker. I'm not familiar with `sequel`.

These gems introduce their own syntax for communicating with the database that is intended to abstact away the database-specific implementation details. I.e. a query like `User.where(verified: true).includes(:posts).order(created_at: :desc)` will list users ordered by most-recent creation date and include their' posts (performing a join behind the scenes). This Ruby syntax will compile to db-specific code based on what adapter and configuration you've specified.

Look into Sinatra and DataMapper; there are many tutorials.

Also look into Rails and how to configure Rails to use MySQL or Postgres instead of (its default) SQLite. You will find that the ORM (ActiveRecord) code doesn't change regardless of which you use.